How to use imu plugin with ros2 control
I have setup ros2 control with ackerman drive which works properly and lets me control the vehicle by publishing to ros2 topics. Now I want to add an IMU sensor and following this tutorial: https://docs.nav2.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html?highlight=imu_plugin
As per the tutorial, I have added the IMU sensor as follows:
<link name="imu_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="Cyan">
                <color rgba="0 1.0 1.0 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value=".1" />
            <inertia ixx="0.145833" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.145833" iyz="0.0" izz="0.125" />
        </inertial>
    </link>




 <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
       <parent link="base_link" />
       <child link="imu_link" />
       <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_height/2}" />
   </joint>  

<gazebo reference="imu_link">
       <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
           <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
               <ros>
                   <namespace>/demo</namespace>
                   <remapping>~/out:=imu</remapping>
               </ros>
               <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
           </plugin>
           <always_on>true</always_on>
           <update_rate>100</update_rate>
           <visualize>true</visualize>
           <imu>
               <angular_velocity>
                   <x>
                       <noise type="gaussian">
                           <mean>0.0</mean>
                           <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
                           <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
                           <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
                       </noise>
                   </x>
                   <y>
                       <noise type="gaussian">
                           <mean>0.0</mean>
                           <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
                           <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
                           <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
                       </noise>
                   </y>
                   <z>
                       <noise type="gaussian">
                           <mean>0.0</mean>
                           <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
                           <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
                           <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
                       </noise>
                   </z>
               </angular_velocity>
               <linear_acceleration>
                   <x>
                       <noise type="gaussian">
                           <mean>0.0</mean>
                           <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
                           <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
                           <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
                       </noise>
                   </x>
                   <y>
                       <noise type="gaussian">
                           <mean>0.0</mean>
                           <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
                           <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
                           <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
                       </noise>
                   </y>
                   <z>
                       <noise type="gaussian">
                           <mean>0.0</mean>
                           <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
                           <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
                           <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
                       </noise>
                   </z>
               </linear_acceleration>
           </imu>
       </sensor>
   </gazebo>

When started however, I get the following error:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] Library [/opt/ros/humble/lib/libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so] does not export any plugins. The symbol [IgnitionPluginHook] is missing, or it is not externally visible.

I am wondering if above usage of the plugin is not compatible with the ros2 control package.
Thanks

I am posting the answer here. I have been using gazebo fortress and the correct library and plugin name is different. Correct one is:
<plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-imu-system.so"
                name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Imu">


Thanks for posting the solution, I think you mark your answer as solving the question yourself ..
